# How to print the numbers between the range in mysql query forex: range 0 to 20(012..20).

Tags: mysql

I want to print the numbers between the range for example 0 to 20 (012345..20) using mysql query.

Comment: Do you want one number on each row?

Comment: yes i need to print each row.

Comment: @radha: if your problem is resolved. consider accepting best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a custom stored procedure, you can't select a range of numbers based on minimum and maximum parameters from just a query alone.

What you can do is create a range table storing numbers on each row:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    num INT NOT NULL
);
```

Then insert numbers: (1-20 or however high you think you'll need them):

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (0),  (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  
                           (5),  (6),  (7),  (8),  (9),  
                           (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), 
                           (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), 
                           (20);
```

Then you can SELECT a range of numbers like so:

```
SELECT num
FROM   numbers
WHERE  num BETWEEN 0 AND 20
```

Comment: In my table i'm not stored in sequential range. its a random order. For example i store 1,3,5. i'm not maintain the sequential order.

Comment: @radha, I'm not sure I fully understand. Do you already have a table that stores numbers, and you want to select a range?

Comment: @radha: a table does **not** have a "sequential order". Use an ORDER BY when selecting them.

Comment: What my question is in 0 to 20. what are all the numbers i used to stored

Comment: i need to listout the remaining things.